# MopaBootstrapBundle Could not find composer.phar

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, bundle

I'm trying to install the MopaBootstrapBundle, I created a view with the following code:

```
{% extends 'MopaBootstrapBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Yourapp{% endblock %}

{# and define more blocks ... #}
```

but when I navigate to that view I get the following exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Unable to find file "@MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js".") in "MopaBootstrapBundle::base.html.twig".
```

I believe this may be due to not being able to install LESS, I get the following error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Project>php app/console mopa:bootstrap:symlink:less
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.



  [RuntimeException]
  Could not find composer.phar



mopa:bootstrap:symlink:less [-f|--force] [-m|--manual] [--no-symlink] [pathToTwi
tterBootstrap] [pathToMopaBootstrapBundle]
```

Even though I have composer installed and it works when I do the following:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Project>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file.
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
Installing assets using the hard copy option
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for FL\FifaLeagueBundle into web/bundles/fifaleague
Installing assets for Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle into web/bundles/mopabootstrap

Installing assets for Acme\DemoBundle into web/bundles/acmedemo
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodi
stribution
Checking Symlink ... OK
```

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.9.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "version": "master",
                "name": "twbs/bootstrap",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/master",
                    "type": "zip"
                 }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures" : "dev-master",    
        "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master",
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
        "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look at [source code](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaComposerBridge/blob/master/src/Mopa/Bridge/Composer/Adapter/ComposerAdapter.php#L68-#L85), you'll see that the error comes from library not able to find it in your system, specifically I'm assuming that [this](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaComposerBridge/blob/master/src/Mopa/Bridge/Composer/Adapter/ComposerAdapter.php#L41) line fails because windows doesn't have `which` command.

I'm guessing the solution would be to use `composer.phar` file directly in project directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the twbs/bootstrap bundle you might find that it has installed, among other scripts, transition.js but mopabootstrapbundle base.html.twig requests bootstrap-transition.js. If this is the case I think you're going to have to rename the scripts or edit base.html.twig. I had twitter/bootstrap, which contains bootstrap-transition.js installed, so I adjusted the symlink.
I'm not sure what the package actually gives me.